# Xamarin Live Player won't pair

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to code in VS2017 in C#. I want use the Xamarin Live Player which I have installed on my iPad. The problem is that Xamarin doesn't show up in Tools > Options so I have no way of pairing XLP with VS. When making a new cross-platform project I only get Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms), in stead of the ones I see that other people get. 
I also want to add that the Xamarin fora are unclear and this forum doesn't have anything relevant.

Visual Studio Community 2017 15.6.6

Xamarin Live Player 1.5.174 (674)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Xamarin Live Player, you can use Gorilla Player which is much better than Xamarin Live Player. Install it in your desktop and on phone as well, use this link for downloading it: https://grialkit.com/gorilla-download/?ref=uxd

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the site doesn't mention the use of C#. And, if possible, I would like to use C#.